# PHP To google spreadsheet (docs api) with zend - DOMDocument cannot parse XML

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-apps-script

I was using zend to publish data from form to google spreadsheet, for almost a year now. Yesterday all of a sudden it stopped working. I highly believe that something got changed on google api that I can't address.

My code is taken from this link: http://www.farinspace.com/saving-form-data-to-google-spreadsheets/ which is explaining it very well and professional, which made my life easier.

This is the error showing when I submit the form now:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_Exception' with message 'DOMDocument cannot parse XML: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input' in /fake/path/zend/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php:830 Stack trace: #0 /fake/path/zend/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php(789): Zend_Gdata_App::importString('', 'Zend_Gdata_Spre...', NULL, NULL) #1 /fake/path/zend/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php(210): Zend_Gdata_App->importUrl('https://spreads...', 'Zend_Gdata_Spre...', NULL) #2 /fake/path/zend/library/Zend/Gdata.php(162): Zend_Gdata_App->getFeed('https://spreads...', 'Zend_Gdata_Spre...') #3 /fake/path/zend/library/Zend/Gdata/Spreadsheets.php(150): Zend_Gdata->getFeed('https://spreads...', 'Zend_Gdata_Spre...') #4 /fake/path/Google_Spreadsheet.php(252): Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets->getSpreadsheetFeed() #5 /fake/path/Google in /fake/path/zend/library/Zend/Gdata/App.php on line 830
```

Is anyone familiar with this or know how to fix the problem? If you can share the link where explanation might lay please do so.

I've tried updating zend and reading through google docs but found nothing.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: You have a variable somewhere (I suppose returned from the API) which cannot be parsed by `new DOMDocument()` because it's empty. Could be lots of things.

Comment: So basically nothing to do with a form, but with api that return information? Is there a way I can troubleshoot it somehow?

Comment: It is something to do with a form, because when I try to remove the array it works (obviously not importing data but yeah), I tried to use plain text instead of variables to check if that was causing the problems but without success...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ClientLogin isn't working...the author of the code will have to switch to oAuth. It can't fetch any of the spreadsheet attributes, including id.

I use the code from farinspace for multiple sites so I'm waiting on this too. https://github.com/farinspace/google-spreadsheet/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

That deprecated ClientLogin, it works again!
It was such a surprise on the eve of the conference Google I / O?
I had to write a self-made solution. Third-party libraries were in basically unusable, 
I wrote about 10 methods, I think it is better than the alternatives, which are too complex and cumbersome.
Not yet ready to put on github)